# How to forward pointer events

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, touch-event

I was able to get this working in iOS but I am having trouble with Win 8.  What I need to do is this:

I have a drawing view that is the forward most child of a `ScrollViewer`.  When I enable drawing mode from a button in the app bar, this view becomes active.  With one touch, I want the user to be able to perform the current drawing action, but with two touches I want the touches to go to the scroll view instead for scrolling and zooming.  I am able to distinguish between 1 and 2 (or more) fingers, but I don't know what to do after that point.

I tried removing the manipulation mode from the drawing view so that it would not block the scroll view, but the touches continued to be swallowed by the drawing view.  I also tried calling `ReleasePointerCapture` but that had no effect either.  How can I forward touch events using the WinRT API?

For some more information, I am making use of the PointerPressed, PointerChanged, etc events in the drawing view.